# MariaDB galera cluster with Mroonga in wrapper mode doesn't synch

Tags: replication, mariadb, galera, data-synchronization, mariadb-10.3

MariaDB Galera Cluster states that the storage engine needs to be InnoDB.

I am using Mroonga on some tables in wrapper mode {which uses InnoDB under the hood as storage engine}.

The problem I am facing is broken synch.

All the standard InnoDB tables get replicated/synched perfectly fine but the tables that are using Mroonga do not get synched for some reason. Any clue what might be the reason?

[EDIT]

Here is the CREATE TABLE SQL

```
CREATE TABLE `employees` (
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `interview_memo` text NOT NULL,
  `caution_notes` text NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  FULLTEXT KEY `idx_employees_interview_memo` (`interview_memo`) COMMENT 'tokenizer "TokenMecab"',
  FULLTEXT KEY `idx_employees_caution_notes` (`caution_notes`) COMMENT 'tokenizer "TokenMecab"'
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COMMENT='engine "InnoDB"'
```

Comment: Can you provide example create statement(s) for the relevant table(s)? Related question here: [Will “bridge” storage engines work with MariaDB Galera Cluster?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/104035/will-bridge-storage-engines-work-with-mariadb-galera-cluster) Also, what error messages (if any) are you seeing?

Comment: Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE` for one of the unsync'd tables.

Comment: Shouldn't that say `ENGINE=Mroonga ... COMMENT='engine "InnoDB"'`? The [documentation on wrapper mode](http://mroonga.org/docs/tutorial/wrapper.html#how-to-use-full-text-search) seems to say so.

Comment: Also, running that CREATE statement with `ENGINE=Mroonga` gives me this warning: `Warning | 1112 | specified tokenizer for fulltext index <TokenMecab> doesn't exist. The default tokenizer for fulltext index <TokenBigram> is used instead.`